QGIS Layout - zoom to extent of objects within an atlas feature
Scenario: In my layout I have an atlas setup where the pages refer to the parcel number. In these parcels are different objects (e.g. construction areas, fences etc.) set to display in the legend. In some cases the parcel is very big, but the objects are concentrated in a small area.
Problem: I am looking for a way to control the extent of the layout by the atlas, but instead of referring to the parcel size, I want the atlas to zoom in to the extent of the objects inside the parcel.

How many atlas features do you have? If the objects inside the parcels are from different layers, the simplest would be to create a new atlas layer based on the parcels, but representing a view extent encompassing the objects of interest.

Or, you have to merge all the construction area, fences, and other objects layers together and then group them by parcel. Then use this layer as an invisible atlas layer.

thank you for the comment. If there is no way to do that by manipulating the filtersettings in atlas, this is a reasonable solution. Thank you!
